# Android use LEFT_RIGHT in jfeinstein SlidingMenu

Tags: android, android-sliding

in my application i want to have two sliding menu, left with right, in this library source file i found `LEFT_RIGHT` option, i think i can have this ability in application but i can not find any document to how to create two sliding menu.

```
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.slide_menu_ketabeavval_list);

    // customize the SlidingMenu
    mSlidingMenu = getSlidingMenu();
    mSlidingMenu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shape_sliding_menu_shadow);
    mSlidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.sliding_menu_offset);
    mSlidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    mSlidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    mSlidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    mSlidingMenu.setFadeEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure what LEFT_RIGHT does, but what you want to do is create two different Sliding Menus. Simply set one to the LEFT mode and one to the RIGHT mode, as follows:

```
// Initialize the left sliding menu
mSlidingMenuLeft = new SlidingMenu(this);
mSlidingMenuLeft.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT); // Define the orientation to the left

// Initialize the right sliding menu
mSlidingMenuRight = new SlidingMenu(this);
mSlidingMenuRight.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT); // Define the orientation to the right
```

Afterwards, deal with each separately, including setting their contents.

There are quite a few optimizations you want to make, including disabling one SlidingMenu if the other is open. If you'd like to see two SlidingMenus in action with optimizations - although you'll have to sift through the entire Activity - feel free to go see this application with two SlidingMenus [here](https://github.com/jawadmn/OneCoolThing/blob/master/app/src/main/java/edu/umich/engin/cm/onecoolthing/Core/ActivityMain.java).

Hope this helps~